# Change specified style via css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, selector

I know this is an old question, and similar questions (solved) are even more complicated. But I've tried and couldn't figure it out myself.

I have

```
<div style="color:white; padding:10px">Text</div>
```

I want to change its color to red:

```
div[style*="color:white"]{color:red}

$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('color') == 'white';
}).css("color", "red");
```

I tried both css and javascript, with or without whitespace, use either hex or RGB color code.

Comment: I think your return statement is just returning true and not the element. anyway, what type of error are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log` or `alert`? You'll immediately see what's happening...`console.log($(this).css('color'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that it's not returning what you're expecting. It's actually returning an RGB string `rgb(255, 255, 255)`, rather than 'white'. Change that and you're golden.

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw73w/)

Answer (score 2):

Actually `$(this).css('color')` returns `rgb(255, 255, 255)` so you can use

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
}).css("color", "red");
```

[**Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uXzJM/)

Comment: Thank you very much! (but I'll mark Apropos's answer my T-up, because he was 10s faster ^_^)

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery API document of .css(), the following sentence is written.

"Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)."

So, I think the simply `return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';` may also has some problem in the future.

And here I suggest use css class to  implement it as the following:

```
.white{color:white;}
.red{color:red;}

$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('white');
}).removeClass('white').addClass('red');
```

And why `div[style*="color:white"]{color:red}` does not work, this is because inline css has the highest priority out of the three ways.

Comment: Thank you very much. Fortunately, I want to do something for me only. and I can't change the html.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something very funky there, the filter function shouldn't be used like that. To select a dom element and change its css with jquery do this `$('div').css({'color': 'red'});`

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kB53t/)

For a proper introduction to jquery I'd recommend this video by the [amazing Chris Coyer](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/20-introduction-to-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Inline CSS takes over any internal or external stylesheet. If you have the ability to remove the inline css on that particular element and replace it with something like `<div class="myElememt"></div>` that would be ideal. As for using jQuery I got it to change by using the CSS method without the filter:

```
$('div').css('color', 'blue');
```